# Fill local array pointing to field of derived class, but later field empty

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, superobject

I must be overlooking something in my web service...

Data structures:

```
TResIDNameRec = record
   id  : Integer;
   name: String;
end;

TResIDNameArr = array of TResIDNameRec;

TResBase = class(TJSONStructure)  // just a class(TObject)
private
public
   &type       : String;
   success     : Integer;
   errormessage: String;
   threadid    : Integer;
   constructor Create; overload;       // empty
   constructor Create(ADescendantClassName: String); overload;  // sets &type
end;

TResClass = class of TResBase;

TResGetList = class(TResBase)
private
public
   activities, 
   projects,   
   customers: TResIDNameArr;
   constructor Create; overload;    // inherited Create(Self.ClassName);
end;
```

and then a

```
type
  TWebAct = (
   ttlogin,
   ...
   ttgetlist,
   ...
   ttgetversion
   );

const
  cWebActStructures: Array[TWebAct] of
  record
     RequestClass : TReqClass;
     ResponseClass: TResClass;
  end
  = (
     { ttlogin     } (RequestClass: TReqLogin;      ResponseClass: TResLogin;),
     ...
     { ttgetlist   } (RequestClass: TReqGetList;    ResponseClass: TResGetList;),
     ...
     { ttgetversion} (RequestClass: TReqGetVersion; ResponseClass: TResGetVersion;)
    );
```

I have a private field on my WebModule:

```
FResponse: TResBase;     // Response object
```

In the WebmoduleBeforeDispatch, FWebAct is a ttgetlist, and I do:

```
lResponseClass := cWebActStructures[FWebAct].ResponseClass;
FResponse      := lResponseClass.Create(lResponseClass.ClassName);  
// FResponse.ClassName is TResGetList, OK
```

In the OnAction handler for the TWebActionItem that handles the 'ttgetlist', here is the essential part:

```
var   
   lListArr : TResIDNameArr;
begin   
   lListArr := (FResponse as TResGetList).activities;

   with AClientDataSet do  
   begin
      Open;
      SetLength(lListArr,RecordCount);  // Pre-allocate (currently 152)
      l := 0;
      First;
      while not EOF do
      begin
         if SomeConditionMet then
         begin
            lListArr[l].id   := FieldByName(lIDVeld).AsInteger;
            lListArr[l].name := FieldByName(SName).AsString;
            Inc(l);
         end;
         Next;
      end;
      Close;
      SetLength(lListArr,l+1);  // Adjust (l is now 108)
    end;
    FResponse.success := 1;
```

lListArr shows correct data at this moment, object inspector shows:

`((3, 'Activiteit 3'), (4, 'Activiteit 3.1'), (5, 'Activiteit 3.2'), (10, 'Activiteit 3.3'), (8, 'Activiteit 5'),...`

In WebmoduleAfterDispatch:

```
var lJSO: ISuperObject;
begin
   lJSO := FResponse.ToJson;
```

LJSO.AsString does have the correct fields (&type, success, ... activities, ... ), and e.g. success=1, **but activities is empty**:

```
{
"errormessage":"",
"success":1,
"projects":[],
"threadid":1556,
"type":"ttgetlistresult",
"customers":[],
"activities":[]
}
```

What am I overlooking? Is maybe the `lListArr := (FResponse as TResGetList).activities` in the OnAction handler 'not good enough'?

BTW Feel free to update the question title, this was the best I could come up with.

Comment: You don't need to pass the class name as a parameter. The ancestor class already knows the descendant class name the same way the descendant class knows it: by reading `Self.ClassName`. `ClassName` isn't a virtual function, but it behaves like one nonetheless because it discovers the class name by reading the appropriate field of the [VMT](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/vmt). Anything that depends on the VMT is implicitly virtual. (Marking a function as virtual tells the compiler, "Put this function's address in the VMT.")

Comment: @Rob Thanks for that tip. If I understand correctly, this works because my *TResBase = class(TJSONStructure)* and *TJSONStructure = class(TObject)* and TObjects' Create is virtual? (Although it does not say so in unit System?)

Comment: No, TObject.Create is not virtual. ClassType always returns the name of the most derived class — the run-time type of the object. In that sense, ClassType is virtual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign `lListArr`, the local variable receives a *reference* to the same array that the `activities` field references. However, when you call `SetLength(lListArr, ...)`, that makes `lListArr` refer to a *new* array, completely separate from the one it referenced before.

If you want the field to refer to the same array, you need to assign it back to the field:

```
(FResponse as TResGetList).activities := lListArr;
```

You can make that assignment at any time after the length has been set. Changes the the *contents* of the array will be visible through either variable. Changing the *length* is not the same as changing the contents, though. Changing the length re-allocates the entire array and gives a new, unique array.